# Managing Layer's Visibility in DynamicMapServiceLayer iOS

Tags: arcgis-ios

I'm working on a iOS mobile application using Arcgis SDK.
There are number of layers(and sublayers) in my Dynamic map service.I want to turn ON/OFF visibility of selected layers(as well as their sublayers) depending on user's choice.
I tried doing so by setting 'visibleLayers' property of my AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer.But it works only once i.e. when I turn ON any layer's visibility, it gets visible (along with some other layers/sub layers as well). After that when I try to turn OFF this layer's visibility,It doesn't do so.